# Leaving a margin towards the right in Android for a View

Tags: android

I have defined a layout which looks like this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/something"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textSize="25dp"/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/something"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Basically I want some text on the left and a button on the right, but if i change the android:text from "Test" to something else e.g "Test.........", the position of the button changes on the screen.

How can i set the position of this button to a static margin from the right corner of the screen? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this .

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/something"
        android:text="Test"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/toggle"
        android:textSize="25sp"/>

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And use `sp` for TextSize and `dp` for view size.

Comment: Can you suggest what I can do if I need to place the textView and toggle inside a linearLayout and the linearLayout itself would be inside the relativeLayout?

Comment: I don't get it . You can put any `ViewGroup`inside other . But the rules will be apply to children as per immediate parent . If you still have confusion the Read and `Layouts` in android.

Comment: Ok . With `LinearLayout` you can use `layoutWeight` . But this will lead to unexpected spacing . So `RelativeLayout` is easy and ultimate solution for it .

Comment: I want LinearLayout inside RelativeLayout because then the positioning of the textView is good with respect to the toggle.

Comment: Use `android:layout_centerVertical` for alignment . You do need an extra layout for it. See the updated answer .